# addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView - Custom ListView Crash in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have created a custom `ListView` but my application crash when I open the `ListView`. I try to debug it but i have few experience with android studio

**Error**

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.uapv1703431.tp1/com.example.uapv1703431.tp1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
```

**Custom Adapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    private Context mContext;
    private String[]  Title;
    private int[] imge;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int ressourceId, List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, ressourceId, items);
        mContext = context;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Title.length;
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView title;
        ImageView i1;
        i1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(Title[position]);
        i1.setImageResource(imge[position]);

        return (row);
    }
}
```

**list_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RowItem**

```
public class RowItem {
    private int imageId;
    private String title;

    public RowItem(int imageId, String title) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }
    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + "\n";
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
// create the custom adapter
        rowItems  = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < countryList.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(id[i], countryList[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rowItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logcat error: "addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView" in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576219/logcat-error-addviewview-layoutparams-is-not-supported-in-adapterview-in-a)

Comment: You should use `ViewHolder` pattern . Try using `RecyclerView` . `ListView` is legacy now ,.

Comment: I have already tried the solution Logcat error: "addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView" in a ListView