# Adding Images and text to android gridview

Tags: java, mysql, android-fragments, gridview

I am getting the exception when running my app.
I have tried the answers given on similar question without any success as I am using a fragment

Here is my Gridview Adapter code

```
      public class FoodGridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context f;
ArrayList<Food> foods;

public FoodGridviewAdapter(Context f, ArrayList<Food> foods){
    this.f = f;
    this.foods = foods;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return foods.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return foods.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(view==null){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(f).inflate(R.layout.food_layout,viewGroup,false);
    }
    TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView cost = view.findViewById(R.id.cost);
    ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    final Food food = (Food) this.getItem(position);
    name.setText(food.getTitle());
    cost.setText(food.getCost());
    //check if there is an image returned
    if(food.getImage()!= null && food.getImage().length()>0){
        Picasso.get().load(food.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.foodfuzzlogo).into(image);
    }else{
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.foodfuzzlogo).into(image);

    }
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(f, food.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

The purpose is to pass the items to the grid view adapter and inflate it with the items

here is my code for retrieving the items from mysql database with a php RESTful api

```
    public class DataRetriever {
private static final String URL_FOOD = "http://192.168.100.250:8082/foodfuzzbackend/auth/login.php";
private final Context f;
private FoodGridviewAdapter foodGridviewAdapter;

public DataRetriever(Context f) {
    this.f = f;
}
public void retrieveFood(final GridView gridView, final ProgressBar myprogressbar){
    final ArrayList <Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();
    myprogressbar.setIndeterminate(true);
    myprogressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    AndroidNetworking.get(URL_FOOD).setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM).build().getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            Food food;
            try{
                for(int i=0; i<response.length();i++){
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String cost = jsonObject.getString("cost");
                    String image = jsonObject.getString("image");
                    food = new Food(URL_FOOD+"../images/"+ image, name, cost);
                    foods.add(food);
                }
                foodGridviewAdapter = new FoodGridviewAdapter(f,foods);
                myprogressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }catch (JSONException e){
                myprogressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
            myprogressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            anError.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I then have my fragment code like this

```
     public class Food extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "Food";
GridView food;
ProgressBar myprogressbar;
public Food() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food, container, false);
    food = view.findViewById(R.id.FoodContainer);
   myprogressbar = view.findViewById(R.id.foodProgressBar);
    new DataRetriever(getActivity()).retrieveFood(food,myprogressbar);

    return view;
}
   }
```

Finally this is the layout of the gridview xml adapter

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
        android:src="@drawable/foodfuzzlogo"
        tools:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/food_fuzz_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/food"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ksh_000_00"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:typeface="serif"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What could I be doing wrong and how can I correct it or who has any link that can help me achieve to pull images and text from mysql db and pass them to a gridview using php and java?

This is the error I get

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
    at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:862)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at com.otemainc.foodfuzzapp.fragment.Food.onCreateView(Food.java:33)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:168)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20009)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20009)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20009)
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20009)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20009)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20009)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20009)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
```

Comment: I have added the logcat file for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @Zima said, I noticed that the gridview adpater was never being added to the adapter, I thus added this line to the dataretriever class

```
     gridView.setAdapter(foodGridviewAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on  [original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17203281/10999505)   :

> For others who have this problem and have inflated a layout in
>   `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView`, set the `parent` parameter to `null`, as
>   in `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);`